# Guidelines for building Data Acces Layer with SQL

Tags: java, .net, sql, data-access-layer

There are a lot of information on building DAL with ORM ((N)Hibernate, LINQ to SQL). But I can't find any recomendations on doing it with plain SQL or mixed (ORM + SQL) approach.

I wonder, are there any resources (sites, books) on this subject?

Besides common best practices I've got a few points of interest:

- how organize storing of sql strings
- dynamic generation of sql strings
- transforming queries resultsets to domain objects
- querying associated collections
- minimize boilerplate data access code

Answer (score 1):

[ExploringDifferentDatabaseOptions](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExtendingNerdDinnerExploringDifferentDatabaseOptions.aspx)